# Linked animations: the first one is instant

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation

The following function should A. make a view large B. wait for 5 seconds and C. shrink it again. The problem is that A happens instantly rather than in two seconds.

```
- (void) showAndHide {
CGRect r = self.frame;
float right = r.origin.x + r.size.width, h = r.size.height, y = r.origin.y;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.frame = CGRectMake(right - 400, y, 400, h);
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                                           delay:5
                                         options: UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve |
                      UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |
                      UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.frame = CGRectMake(right - 40, y, 40, h);
                                      }
                                      completion:nil];

                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

}

What could be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put the second animation in the completion handler of the first one:

```
- (void) showAndHide {
CGRect r = self.frame;
float right = r.origin.x + r.size.width, h = r.size.height, y = r.origin.y;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.frame = CGRectMake(right - 400, y, 400, h);
                 }
                 completion:^{
                 [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                                       delay:5
                                     options: UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.frame = CGRectMake(right - 40, y, 40, h);
                                      }
                                      completion:NULL];
                 }];
}
```

The problem with your approach is, that the two animations are queued simultaneously. If you want to stick with your code I think adding `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` to the options of the second animation might fix your problem too. Not quite sure about that though.